# RL Custom Environment Stable Baselines

Tags: python, environment, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, stable-baselines

I am training a custom environment on gym, but when i try to apply the learn method, i get this error:

*RuntimeError: Calling torch.geqrf on a CPU tensor requires compiling PyTorch with LAPACK. Please use PyTorch built with LAPACK support.*

Does anybody know how I can fix it?

Thanks a lot

Comment: "Please use PyTorch built with LAPACK support." The message literally tells you what to do, the developers put it there for a reason.

Comment: Hi, 
sorry, I dont know what that means. That is the reason I asked for help. 
Thanks for your message anyway